# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; when I use generic

Tags: java, generics

When I run code below:

```java
public class GenericTest<T> {

    private T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[5];//泛型不能直接创建，但是可以这样转型

    public static void func(GenericTest<String> gt){
        for(int i = 0; i < gt.arr.length; i++){
            if(gt.arr[i] == null)
                System.out.print(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GenericTest<String> gt = new GenericTest<>();
        //gt.func();
        func(gt);
    }
}
```

I got a error:

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; [duplicate]

But when I run code like this (though they like very similar)：

```java
public class GenericTest<T> {

    private T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[5];//泛型不能直接创建，但是可以这样转型

    public void func(){
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] == null)
                System.out.print(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GenericTest<String> gt = new GenericTest<>();
        gt.func();
        //func(gt);
    }
}
```

I can get what I want to see:

```
01234
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Could someone give me a light?

Comment: an Object array `new Object[5]` is not an valid String array `GenericTest<String> gt = new GenericTest<>();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, they may look similar, but they are not.

The thing is that with `func()`, the compiler knows nothing about the actual generic type of `GenericTest`, except that is is eventually an `Object`. Retrieving `arr.length` will just work fine.

But then look at `void func(GenericTest<String> gt)`. The argument mandates that a `GenericTest<String>` is passed in. So the compiler inserts a type cast for `arr` to a `String[]`:

```java
((String[]) gt.arr).length
```

And guess what – `gt.arr` is *actually* an `Object[]`, which can, of course, not be converted to a `String[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems that I haven't understood generic, because I thought that when I run`GenericTest<String> gt = new GenericTest<>();`, I was creating an arr of String... **but according to your answer, I was creating an arr of Object even I use `GenericTest<String> gt = new GenericTest<>();`, Right?**